# Show data of two table not to join in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have two tables:

- **campaign**: `id`, `name`, `status`, `created_at`
- **active_campaign:** `id`, `campaign_id`, `price`, `quantity`

Now i will display the value of the table fields: `active_campaign` by `campaign_id`.

Is there a way that I don't need to join the `campaign` table and still display the `name` of the `campaign` table according to the `campaign_id` of the `active_campaign` table?

---

**Example:**

`campaign`:

| id | name | status | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | test 1 | 1 | 2021/07/01 |

`active_campaign`

| id | campaign_id | price | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 10 | 5 |

Now I want to display by `active_campaign` table:

| name | price | quantity | createdAt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| test 1 | 10 | 5 | 2021/07/01 |

Not join? Is there any way please help me? thanks.

Comment: Have you tried [`relations`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships) ? It is the most basic Laravel DB stuff...

Comment: Best practise is to do join. if you will not join then you will have to run two queries one after another that will be costly. depends on your scenario.

Comment: Simple Used HasOne Realtion and then used it

Comment: 1) Laravel Relationship is what will help you, and release you from joining.
2) joining is also easy if you want to try with DB::RAW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple Used https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one

ActiveCampaign Model

```
public function campaign() {
    return $this->hasOne(Campaign::class);
}
```

Controller Method

```
$result = ActiveCampaign::first();
```

And you can access Direct it.

```
$result->campaign->name;
```

Comment: Thanks bro. I handle at controller : `$list =  ActiveCampaign::select('id','campaign_id')->get();` .Then i foreach variable $list : `foreach ($list as $val) { $val->campaign->name }` , there is an error with it : Trying to get property 'name' of non-object .

Comment: $val['campaign']['name']

Comment: and used with('campaign')

Answer (score 0):

You can add method in model of table "active_campaign" like below code.

```
public function campaign()
{
    $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Campaign', "id", "campaign_id")->select("name");
}
```

Then you can access name like below

```
$active_campaign->campaign->name;
```